# How does "Recycle master recycle bin" app recovering deleted files ?

Tags: applications, data-recovery, file-system

There are many apps that recovers deleted data(images, video, PDF) i.e Disk digger , Dumpster e.t.c and these apps also ask for root , but here i want to know the process/methodology of simple recovering of files which are accidentally deleted.

In Recycle master recycle bin what have they tried to recover files using no root and it does provide the deleted files in app list view.

So to perform such task what i have to do in my app.

1) Are they implementing their own file manager by over riding/uninstall the default file manager so that user when ever open files it must interact with their file manager.
If so then how to override default file manager ?

2) Are they over riding system calls to force operating system functionality?

3) Or there is some thing else?

Comment: can any one help if they know what is being performed here.

Comment: You can check that by installing app and viewing through logcat what intents are being sent and received by the app while deleting a file. I don't have time right now, I may check that later. If the app is providing it's own file explorer to delete files, that's very simple. It's simply moving them to a hidden directory.

Comment: Can you provide the process how to implement or create such a file explorer that delete files because i have never worked on it .

Comment: I wish I could but I know almost nothing about Android app development. MiXplorer has this feature but I don't think that's open source. That simply moves files to `/sdcard/.recycle` folder on deletion. You may contact the developer for help. And development questions get more attention on https://stackoverflow.com/